# 401 error in Windows server 2012 after disabling crypto

Tags: authentication, iis, cryptography, windows-server-2012-r2, http-status-code-401

We had the following issue in our Production Environemt:
When we disabled some weak crypto in our IIS Server 8.5 (Using IISCrypto) the server, after we try to login on the webpage, shows a 401 error

The crypto and ciphers that we were trying to configure was this

[Crypto Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laso2.png)

[Ciphers Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HxZs.png)

The error after we applied changes and restarted the server was this

[401 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMQ4k.png)

However, when we applied the same changes in our QA Enviroment and we didn't had that issue, as a matter of fact, we checked if IIS in both enviroments had a different configuration, still, the configuration was the same in both enviroments. If we reverse the change and enable all of the Crypto algorithms, the problem dissappears

[IIS Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtlZ8.png)

We also checked our **Web.config** in order to check if the authentication methods on both environments was different, however, both lines are exactly the same

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="20" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Login.aspx" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow roles="Admin, User" />
</authorization>
```

Can anybody help us out here with this issue? none of the workarounds and solutions we have looked for have worked or they don't apply (Mainly because we do not use Windows Authentication in our website)

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** Anonymous Authentication has the same configuration on both sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, I needed to first update the servers to the last Windows security update! after that, everything worked fine!